# Show that two linearly independent paths give the same number of turns around the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Are $\alpha, \beta:[a,b] \rightarrow \Re^2 -{0}$ closed class paths $C^1$. If $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ are linearly independents $\forall t \in [a,b]$ so $\alpha$ e $\beta$ give the same number of turns around the origin.

obs.: Tried to show that: $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\alpha {\delta\theta}$ = $\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_\beta{\delta\theta}$, but do not know exactly how to use the fact that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are linearly independents.

Obs.:  $\delta \theta = \Large{\frac{-y dx + xdy}{x^2 + y^2}}$